Contact Dashboard for non-administrator users doesn't display their relationships
On the user dashboard "Your Contacts / Organizations" are only visible for Administrator users, even though it has been enabled on the Display Preferences - Contact Dashboard:

For logged in users this section doesn't appear on their dashboard:

Is there anything else needs to be configured for non-Administrator Contacts?
Thank you!

Do they have permission to access their contacts?

do you have the Permissioned Relationship extension? https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls

Yes, I have both, the Related Permission Relationship extension and they both have permission to 'View and Update' over each other, but still a non-administrator user can't see their related contacts yet.
